# Expand the logo from a half

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

has anyone any idea if you can do this in jquery? Where clicking on a piece of the logo expands the rest? Example image:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why use jQuery if this can be achieved using CSS?

HTML:

```
<div id='icon-wrapper'>
  <img id='icon' alt='icon' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKhJf.jpg?s=60&g=1'/>
  <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#icon-wrapper{ 
    margin:0 auto;
    height:110px;
    width:110px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /* CSS Transitions */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#icon-wrapper:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
#icon-wrapper:hover{
    width:300px;
}
#icon-wrapper:hover #icon{
    margin-left:200px;
}
#icon{
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    /* Position Absolute to put the icon on the top */
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    /* CSS Transitions */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#icon-wrapper p{
    color:black;
    font-size:35px;
    font-family:arial, helvetica;
    /* Fixed width and float left is needed */
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

It's long but without using jQuery is a plus point.
Note that we need to use **fixed width** for the elements, especially for the **paragraph**.

**UPDATE:**
For transparent icon, we need to hide the text first, using opacity:0;. Then add CSS Transition so we have smooth effect on hover. Finally, show the text on hover with opacity:1;. But this trick has a bug, sometimes the text didn't 'hide' fast, so it's still shown for a time in the icon. The best solution is adding a background color to the icon, using the same color as the container background.

Updated CSS (transparent text):

```
#icon-wrapper:hover p{
    opacity:1;
}

#icon-wrapper p{
    /* ... */
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

Updated CSS (using background color on the icon):

```
#icon{
    /* ... */
    background:white;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd96P/1/)

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd96P/3/) for transparent icon.

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd96P/5/) with background color added to the icon.

Comment: friend, with my logo, it is transparent. I modified some things but it didn't work... print: http://clanload.com.br/images/3UrkL.png

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something you want.

Check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/SdanM/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">    
    <div id="img">Hidden Element</div>
    <div id="btn">Hover to expand</div>
<div>
```

CSS: hide the `hidden element` first

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#img {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    display: none;
}

#btn {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

jQuery: move the blocks

```
$("#container").mouseenter( function() {
    $("#img").animate({
        left: "-=50",
        width: "show",
    }, 1000);

    $("#btn").animate({
        left: "+=50",
    }, 1000);
});

$("#container").mouseleave( function() {
    $("#img").animate({
        left: "+=50",
        width: "hide",
    }, 1000);

    $("#btn").animate({
        left: "-=50",
    }, 1000);
});
```